# Servlet JSP getparameter getattribute returning null

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, getattribute, getparameter

I'm having trouble with passing servlet variables to jsp.

Of course, I also have the web.xml set for the servlet already

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>databaseServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Servlet.databaseServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>databaseServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/dbServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The result is all of the name, owner, species and sex values are null. Can someone help me with this? Thanks

P.S: I also tried to use request.getSession().setAttribute in the servlet, didn't work either

P.P.S: So if I make the following changes:

databaseServlet.java

```
package Servlet;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")

public class databaseServlet extends HttpServlet {
private Connection conn;
private Statement statement;

String name;
String owner;
String species;
String sex;
String birth;
String death;

public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost/STUDENTS",
                "root",
                "");
        statement = conn.createStatement();

        String sql = "SELECT name, owner, species, sex, birth, death FROM pet";
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);

        //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
        while(rs.next()){
            //Retrieve by column name
            name  = rs.getString("name");
            owner = rs.getString("owner");
            species = rs.getString("species");
            sex = rs.getString("sex");
            birth = rs.getString("birth");
            death = rs.getString("death");
        }
        rs.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

protected void doPost (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.setAttribute("NAME", "Hello");
    System.out.println(name);
    request.setAttribute("OWNER",owner);
    request.setAttribute("SPECIES",species);
    request.setAttribute("SEX", sex);
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher=getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/dbServlet.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request,  response);
}
```

}

and this is my new jsp:

```
<body>
Name="${databaseServlet.NAME}" 
Owner="${databaseServlet.OWNER}" 
Species="<%= request.getAttribute("SPECIES") %>"
Sex="<%= request.getSession().getAttribute("SEX") %>"

</body>
```

both Name and Owner returns empty string, while Species and Sex still returns NULL

basically what I'm trying to do is to access MySQL database to retrieve variables from a table, and display it using JSP

Comment: check if your browser accepts cookies or not

Comment: where do you set the attributes with values inside your servlet?

Comment: I added more details to my java servlet, basically all 4 variables are from connection to MySQL database, but I'm just not sure how to actually display the values from those variables to JSP

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have valid values for `name`, `owner`, `species` and `sex` when setting request attribute inside `doPost` method.

Use EL syntax like

```
${NAME}
${OWNER}
${SPECIES}
${SEX}
```

---

**Do not write scriptlets in JSP**, because scriptlets shouldn't be used in JSPs for more than a decade. Learn the JSP [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info), the [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info), and use servlet for the Java code. [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1031945)

Comment: I have tried to use EL syntax as you said, but you can see from my edited code above that it still seem to return empty strings

Comment: @user3172137 : I have answered `${NAME}` not `${databaseServlet.NAME}`. Just use the `${NAME}` or `${param.NAME}`

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher=getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/dbServlet.jsp");
```

I guess it should work.
And use request.getAttribute() 
only, it will return Object type, you will have to cast it

Comment: I tried using this, and using getAttribute only, still returns null

Comment: Have u checked the values before adding them in request??

Answer (score 0):

Just give a scope to your attributes, and you can change your code like this :

```
protected void doPost (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.getSession().setAttribute("NAME", "Hello");
    System.out.println(name);
    request.getSession().setAttribute("OWNER",owner);
    request.getSession().setAttribute("SPECIES",species);
    request.getSession().setAttribute("SEX", sex);
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher=getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/dbServlet.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request,  response);
}
```

And when you handling the attribute make it sessionScope like :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<body>
<c:set var="myName" value="NAME" />
<c:set var="myOwner" value="OWNER" />
Name="${sessionScope[myName]}" 
Owner="${sessionScope[myOwner]}" 
       //etc...
</body>
```

I hope this helps you.